Cannot call Google Gemini API functions in SAPUI5 App
I have integrated Gemini API in SAPUI5 app and the results are coming as well. I am able to get the response JSON when the API key is inserted and can see what models are available. But not able to send the prompt to the model and get the response. I am not sure how to use async and await in UI5, since UI5 by default calls functions in async
This is the code, which I am trying just a basic prompt. askGemini() is the function I am calling to fetch the result
checkGoogleConnection: function() {
            const vBox = this.getView().byId("vb1")
            const APIBtn = this.getView().byId("checkGoogleConn");
            const APIField = this.getView().byId("checkGoogleKey");
            vBox.removeItem(APIBtn);
            vBox.removeItem(APIField);

            const gemKey = this.getView().byId("checkGoogleKey").getValue();
            console.log(gemKey);
            this.GOOGLE_API_KEY = gemKey;
            console.log(this.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

            // call Gemini AI API to check models. 
            const gen_ai = new GenAI.GoogleGenerativeAI(gemKey);
            console.log(gen_ai);
            const models = gen_ai.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash"});
            console.log(models);

            var labelText = "";

            if (models){
                console.log("pass");
                labelText = "available models: " + models.model;
            }else{
                console.log("fail");
                labelText = "no models available right now!!";
            }

            const geminiConnSuccessInfoLabel = new InfoLabel("gcsil1", {
                text: labelText,
                colorScheme: 5
            })
            vBox.addItem(geminiConnSuccessInfoLabel);

        },

        // call Gemini and get resolution. 
        askGemini: function() {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Fetching from Gemini!!");

            const gen_ai2 = new GenAI.GoogleGenerativeAI(this.GOOGLE_API_KEY);
            console.log(gen_ai2);
            const models2 = gen_ai2.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash"});
            console.log(models2);

            const prompt = "Write a story about an AI and magic"
            const result = models2.generateContent(prompt);
            const response = result.response;
            //const text = response.text();
            console.log(response);
            //console.log(text);
        },

What is done wrong here? If I use async and await, errors are shown in console.
this is the app. The Ask button calls the function above.


This article may help you, it covers the usage of async/await in SAPUI5.
Basically, you should mark your call of generateContent function with await:
const result = await models2.generateContent(prompt)

And also mark askGemini function with async:
askGemini: async function() 

Moreover, if askGemini is a handler for a Button's press event, you should wrap it in another function call and use this new function as an event handler, as from my experience async functions are not called when used as an event handler.
